# Apache & URL encoding: Fix broken links with special characters and accents in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I moved my simple HTML website to a new host.
It has hard-coded links with accents in the URL which stopped working.
Apparently the site used ISO-8859-1 and the new host UTF-8

Example of the word "condición" in links looks like:

> condici%F3n

That returns a 404 but if I write

> condici%C3%B3n

on the address bar, it works fine.

So far I've tried editing the .htaccess file adding

> IndexOptions +Charset=ISO-8859-1

Adding "AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1" to apache configuration file.

And running "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 fileA -o fileB"

None of this seems to work and the links are still broken

How can I fix the links on my 500k pages without doing it manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you convert your static html documents to todays unicode standard (UTF-8 encoding)?

Comment: I treied "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 fileA -o fileB" But the links remain the same. I think it would be simplier to make the server understand those links

Comment: If the links remain the same, then either your file is _not_ encoded in 8bit encoding, or your conversion did not convert. Both are situations that can be solved. The advantage of solving the actual issue instead of somehow trying to work around it: you do not lock yourself in for future developments.

Comment: Anyway, I have the impression that you are currently _guessing_ what your actual situation is. It rarely is a good idea to make decisions based on an unknown knowledge base. So my advice: find out what encoding you actually have. Any capable text editor should be usable for that.

Comment: Or, even better, a hex editor. Something like `okteta` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have mixed results from this tools: https://abctool.gitlab.io/encoding-detector/ = windows-1252  --------- Linux file command = HTML document, ISO-8859 text, with very long lines (12516), with CRLF, LF line terminators ------- source code has the following meta tag: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

Comment: I just tried "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8"  and changed the meta tag to UTF-8, links still broken.

Comment: As said: use a hex editor, the only way to really tell what characters there are. I often stumbled about documents actually having _mixed_ , so broken encoding.

Comment: How many links are we talking about, considering that this is a static page? Can't you simply go through them manually?

Comment: okteta confirms is ISO-8859-1. Definitely not possible to fix manually. over 500k files

Comment: That does not mean it is ... You need to consider that technically _any_ document is a valid 8bit encoded document. The thing here: if it were a plain ISO document then the conversion should work flawlessly. It does not, there has to be a reason for that. Just my 2 cents. What I personally did in such situations (back in the times, where 8 bit encoding was still used from time to time ;-) ): use a hex editor to check the actual characters I was interested in. That is how you can actually say what character is at that and that position. Is that a 8 bit character? Or a 2 byte unicode sequence?

Comment: But maybe I am just too picky here. Just follow your heart :-)