# PHP URL encoding special characters fails

Tags: php

I moved my website to a new host. It has links (both internal and external from other websites I don't manage) with accents in the URLs which stopped working. Apparently the site used ISO-8859-1 and the new host UTF-8
I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73612942/apache-url-encoding-fix-broken-links-with-special-characters-and-accents-in-u?noredirect=1#comment129995528_73612942) with PHP.

Example of the word "condición" in links looks like:

```
condici%F3n
```

That returns a 404 but if I write

```
condici%C3%B3n
```

OR

```
condición
```

on the address bar, it works fine.

So far I managed to print the right URL with the following code:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("iso-8859-1");
mb_http_output( "iso-8859-1" );
ob_start("mb_output_handler");
$value  = $_GET['termino'];
echo $value;
?>
```

- 

```
https://example.com/page.php?termino=condici%F3n
```

- Prints condición

The problem comes when I try to pass that word and redirect to an URL

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("iso-8859-1");
mb_http_output( "iso-8859-1" );
ob_start("mb_output_handler");
$value  = $_GET['termino'];
header("Location: https://example.com/$value", true, 301);
?>
```

It switches back to:

```
condici%F3n
```

Why is this happening? How can I solve this?

Comment: _"Why is this happening?"_ - because you still put just the value `condición` into your URL, and leave it up to the client to apply URL encoding ...?

Comment: But if I "put just the value condición into URL" it works. Only when the script does it fails

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   mb_internal_encoding("iso-8859-1");
   mb_http_output( "iso-8859-1" );
   ob_start("mb_output_handler");
   $value  = urlencode($_GET['termino']);
   header("Location: https://example.com/$value", true, 301);
?>
```

And Now print with urldecode()

```
<?php
     echo urldecode($_GET['value'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please note my goal is to fix links, I was printing as a way of debugging only.